# programatically add overlay icon in an activity

Tags: android, icons, android-activity, overlay

I've been searching around in Google for a bit but I can't seem to find what I want to do. I want to be able to programatically add an icon as an overlay in an activity at a specified position without using any xml.

An example of what I mean: http://cdn9.staztic.com/app/a/2326/2326236/pollfish-demo-2-1-s-307x512.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends at layout you are using. If you are using `RelativeLayout`, you can do it this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which is equal with this Java code (except root `RelativeLayout`):

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
ImageView child = new ImageView(this);
child.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

child.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(child);
```

Comment: what if you dont know what the layout of the parent is (e.g the root activity?

Comment: You want something like Facebook chat bubbles or Halo bar from custom Roms?

Comment: there's a link on my original post which shows what I want. I want to be able to display some sort of icon in any activity (in any of the corners for example of any activity. I think this is best done with a FrameLayout

Comment: You want overlay all applications or only your own app?

Comment: any application/activity. think of the icon as part of a library